# if hasclass addclass else removeclass not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

This is my markup

```
<header id="header">
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="homeSecLink" class="active"><a href="#Home" class="homeLink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Partners">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

On page load I am trying to add class `borderGap` on header if `homeSecLink` has `active` class else remove `borderGap`

Here `addClass` working but `removeClass` not working

This is what I have done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#homeSecLink').hasClass("active")) {
        $('#header').addClass('borderGap');
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('borderGap');
    }
});
```

Comment: define `not working` ?

Comment: Looks like this works fine ?http://jsfiddle.net/FRaTH/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/FRaTH/2/

Comment: Please specify what exactly you expect it to do and what it does. "Not working" is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `removeClass` to work you need to remove `active class`

HTML

```
<header id="header">
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="homeSecLink" class="active"><a href="#Home" class="homeLink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Partners">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<a id="toggle">Toggle</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
        if ($('#homeSecLink').hasClass("active")) {
            $('#header').addClass('borderGap');
            $('#homeSecLink').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass('borderGap');
            $('#homeSecLink').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/ZUn7k/)**

Comment: The `active` class is perhaps added by a server-side script? Meaning this is not in the scope of what the OP wants to happen.